# Will Wordpress Update effect my custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am going to create a custom theme for one of my client, he will be reselling it to his customers.
As wordpress updates comes frequently and one has to update the wordpress to ensure security, how can I prevent my theme from update effects? I want to know that as there anyway to update the theme remotely with wordpress updates?
I will be using a custom framework not the wordpress default theme engine.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you've used deprecated functions in your theme, a WordPress Update won't mess anything up. The WordPress update process doesn't touch theme files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress Codex [gives a warning](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress) about updates.

That being said, if you look at the ["Extended Instructions"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions) for updating, it lists files and folders you can delete. It also lists files and folders you SHOULD NOT DELETE. Those "DO NOT DELETE" items are the files and folders not touched by an update.

So... you should ask yourself, "Will I ever need to edit/enhance one of those core files that may be replaced?"

The answer could help you build safer and smarter.